# Module not yet loaded error with require-css plugin

Tags: requirejs

I am working on some codebase where require.js and require-css is used. I am getting following error message on my browser console.

```
Error: Module name "../../../libs/require-css/css!views/../../stylesheets/css/modules/basicTheme" has not been loaded yet for context: _ http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

My requied configuration is as below:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './js/',

    map: {
        '*': {
            'css': '../../../libs/require-css/css'
        }
    },

    paths: {
        ...
        ...     
    },
    ...
    ...
});
```

In my View, I am trying to load it as below:

```
define(function(require) {
    "use strict";
    require("css!../../../stylesheets/css/modules/basicTheme.css");
});
```

I am not getting why this error is getting shown. I also checked that my basicTheme.css file is getting loaded in network tab in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

it is shown because your `require('X')` is used to load a module "synchroneously" from cache, you still need to "load" the module to the page:

```
define(["css!../../../stylesheets/css/modules/basicTheme.css"], function(require) {
    "use strict";
    require("css!../../../stylesheets/css/modules/basicTheme.css");
});
```

or

```
define(function(require) {
    "use strict";
    require(["css!../../../stylesheets/css/modules/basicTheme.css"], function(){
    //ok now it's loaded
  });
});
```